# Hide property from inherited silverlight control

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to hide a property from Intellisense for the `Text` property of the `TextBox` control.

I tried the following, but I get a compile error complaining that the `Text` property is not set as virtual in the base class. I am not trying to remove the property, just hide it from Intellisense. Any ideas?

```
public class MyTextBox:TextBox
{

   [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]     
   [Browsable(false)]
   public override string Text
   {
      get
      {
         return base.Text;
      }
      set
      {
        base.Text = value;
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can use [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier)  keyword to hide it if its not virtual.

Like this:

```
public class MyTextBox:TextBox
{
   [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]     
   [Browsable(false)]
    public new string Text
    {
      get
      {
         return base.Text;
      }
      set
      {
        base.Text = value;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in the code-behind, but doesn't seem to hide it from intellisense in XAML.... Any ideas why?